# Issue importing functions from DLL C++. LNK 2001

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport, lnk2001

I have two projects. One creates a DLL and the other should use functions declared in the DLL, but I have problems implementing this.

In the DLL project I have these declarations:

```
using namespace XClass;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Compute(XClass::XClassInput input, XClassOutput &XClassOutput);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Init( string configFileName);

class xclass
{

public:
    xclass(void);
    xclass(constellation &Constellation, XClass::XClassConfig &XClassConfig);

    void   ComputeWeightingMatrix(constellation &xclass_constellation, char flagIntCont);
    void   ComputeGMatrix(constellation &Constellation, XClass::XClassInput &input);

private:
    int _numberOfSystemStates;
};
```

In the project that has to use the DLL functions I have this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    XClass::XClassConfig xClassConfig;
    XClassOutput xClassOutput;

    XClass::XClassInput input;

    init(input, xClassOutput ); 

    constellation* class_constellation = new constellation(input, xClassConfig);

    xclass* algorithm = new xclass(*xclass_constellation, xClassConfig);


     algorithm->ComputeWeightingMatrix(*xclass_constellation,  'i');


    return 0;
}
```

The code for the ComputeWeighting Matrix function:

```
    void xclass::ComputeWeightingMatrix(constellation &Constellation, char flagIntCont)
    {
        double sigma = 0.0;
        long error;

            ...
    }
```

When I try to build I get his:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall xclass::ComputeWeightingMatrix(class constellation &,char)" (?ComputeWeightingMatrix@xclass@@$$FQAEXAAVconstellation@@D@Z)

Comment: So where is your code for `xclass::ComputeWeightingMatrix`?

Comment: Is it relevant the content of the function? or just its declaration?

Comment: Where is the definition of it, and how are you building the code? ]

Comment: I have edited the post to show both declaration and definition. As for the building, I have added as reference the DLL project, in the project calling the DLL. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: So, are you linking to the .lib file for the xclass DLL?

Comment: I want to be able to call from a separate project, the function ComputeWeightingMatrix which is in a DLL. Am I missing something? 
I am a bit confused about the extern use. Do I have to mark all function in the DLL project as extern if I want them to be available in another project?

Comment: To use a DLL (as "direct code" like you do here), you need to link to a "stub" library that holds a "stub function" (typically, a single jump instruction) that, when the DLL gets loaded, holds the actual address of the DLL function. You need to specify the stub library as part of your build.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33633/discussion-between-dcuser-and-mats-petersson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in Chat, it turns out there are two parts to the solution of this problem:

1. Need to use the stub library from the DLL class.
2. Need to use `class __declspec(dllexport) XClass` to ensure the functionality from the class is exported.